# cannot connect to database sql server on another pc from java app

Tags: java, sql, database, connection

I'm new to java and cannot connect to database sql server on another pc

I tried

```
public class ConnectDB {

        public Connection connect() {
            Connection cn = null;

            try{         
                Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");

                cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.1/HR;instance=MSSQLSERVER", "sa", "pass");

                //cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.1/HR:1433;instance=MSSQLSERVER", "sa", "pass");
                //cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.1;instance=MSSQLSERVER;databaseName=HR", "sa", "pass");


            }catch(ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){

                System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage() );

            } return cn;
        }
    }
```

and got Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect

TCP/IP is enabled and when i ping on cmd no late occur

please anyone can help me.

Comment: what exception u face

Comment: Do you have some log? What happens?

Comment: please be more specific about the issue, provide the stacktrace and a little more context

Comment: i got Error: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you open the remote access on your database?

http://www.sophos.com/fr-fr/support/knowledgebase/118473.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The URL format for `jTDS` is:

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]
```

So, to connect to a database called "HR" hosted by SQL Server running on 192.168.1.1, you may end up with something like this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.1:1433/HR;instance=SQLEXPRESS;user=sa;password=pass
```

Or, if you prefer to use getConnection(url, "sa", "pass"):

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.1:1433/HR;instance=SQLEXPRESS
```

Comment: Thank you, i use sql server 2012 what instance could i use and is it mandatory?

Comment: thanks for your help i will try it tomorrow on the server and give the feed back

Comment: sure dear,if need help let me knw

Comment: similar pblm look http://thusithamabotuwana.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/connecting-to-sql-server-using-jtds/